# RemoveFilter Function Not Working Within Calculate when Last. Date is used as a Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

The RemoveFilter Function is Not Working Within Calculate when Last Date is used as a Filter.

I've simplified my Data/Measure and attached a screenshot.

The Formula within my Measure is as follows:

```
CountRows for LastDate = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sheet1),LASTDATE(Sheet1[Date]),REMOVEFILTERS(Sheet1))
```

I want to count rows only for the last date within the date column. Additionally, Ignore any Filters that are applied within the visuals.

The desired value here should be 4.

This works for all scenarios in the screenshots attached.

Except when "Pre 10" or "01 January 2023" is Selected within the slicers.

The Measure should Ignore All filters within the table.

I think this is due to the fact that neither "2 Jan 2023" nor "Pre 10" have any values for the last date in the data.

Which is wrong, either there's an error within PowerBI or  I'm not understanding how these functions worked.

Would someone be able to advise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering seems to be related to the order of evaluation of filters in DAX.
You want to count the rows of the last date in `Sheet1`, and remove any filters applied to `Sheet1`. However, using `LASTDATE(Sheet1[Date])` is still considering the filters applied before `REMOVEFILTERS(Sheet1)` is called, causing the issues you described.

You might try using `ALL(Sheet1[Date])` to clear all filters from the date column inside the `LASTDATE()` function.

```
CountRows for LastDate = 
VAR LastDateValue = CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[Date]), ALL(Sheet1))
RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sheet1), Sheet1[Date] = LastDateValue)
```

I calculated the last date by using `MAX(Sheet1[Date])` with `ALL(Sheet1)` to ensure that no filters are applied to the date.